# Repeating the same command for x number of times

Tags: r, repeat

I am trying to repeat a same command for x number of times, a simple example would be to read files with same names but different years for 10 times, I can do this

```
yr2001detail<-read.csv("E:/yr2001detail.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header=TRUE )
yr2002detail<-read.csv("E:/yr2002detail.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header=TRUE )
yr2003detail<-read.csv("E:/yr2003detail.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header=TRUE )
yr2004detail<-read.csv("E:/yr2004detail.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header=TRUE )
yr2005detail<-read.csv("E:/yr2005detail.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header=TRUE )
yr2006detail<-read.csv("E:/yr2006detail.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header=TRUE )
yr2007detail<-read.csv("E:/yr2007detail.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header=TRUE )
yr2008detail<-read.csv("E:/yr2008detail.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header=TRUE )
yr2009detail<-read.csv("E:/yr2009detail.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header=TRUE )
yr2010detail<-read.csv("E:/yr2010detail.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header=TRUE )
```

which is bad, because i'm repeating myself and also it is really time consuming if there are way too many files or if i have to repeat too many times. I have tried exploring doing

```
for(i in 1:10){
 paste("yr",2000+i,"detail",sep="")<-read.csv(paste("E:/yr",2000+i,"detail.csv",sep=""),stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header=TRUE )
}
```

which didnt work because of the left side, and also this

```
vector <- rep(NA,10)
for(i in 1:10){
vector[i] <- paste("yr",2000+i,"detail",sep="")
}
for(i in 1:10){
vector[i]<-read.csv(paste("E:/yr",2000+i,"detail.csv",sep=""),stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header=TRUE )
}
```

I am asking as further down along the way, i'll have to deal with my data yearly which means assigning more repetitive commands for each year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sprintf` to create the 'files' and 'filenames'

```
files <- sprintf("E:/yr%ddetail.csv", 2001:2010)
filenames <- sprintf("yr%ddetail", 2001:2010)
```

Or even `paste` can be used

```
files <- paste0("E:/", 2001:2010, "detail.csv")
filenames <- paste0("yr", 2001:2010, "detail")
```

and then loop through the files to read it.  If we need separate objects, use `assign`,

```
for(j in seq_along(filenames)){
    assign(filenames[j], read.csv(files[j], stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE))
}
```

---

However, it is better to read it in a `list` rather than having many objects in the global environment, i.e.

```
lst <- setNames(lapply(files, read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE), filenames)
```

Or a faster option with `fread`

```
library(data.table)
lst <- setNames(lapply(files, fread), filenames)
```

After reading it in a `list`, we can also `rbind` the datasets together to a single one and have an 'id' column to indicate from which file it came from.  This can be useful in several operations.

```
dt <- rbindlist(lst, idcol="Grp")
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, the first part of the solution is what i was looking for, even though it clutters the gobal environment, i would like the option to click into the object for now as compared to list. this is great as i can use other fuctions such as subsetting all the data at once instead of using the subset comment 10times.